# Give a specific pattern from a node during clause

Tags: neo4j

I have the nodes: `(a:charlie)`, `(b:economy)`, and `(c:bicycle)` . I want to create this pattern:

```
create (a:charlie)-[x:wants_make]->(b:economy)->[y:by_using]->(c:bicycle)
```

But it gives me cartesian product. I already thought *to skip the creation of* the node `(b)` giving to relation `[x:want_make]`a property. But node `(b)` has many other relations in the same context(economic context). What I want to get the pattern above.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I want relate node a to node c passing through node b as node b is a very important node related to many others with `:economy`label and cannot be a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your query looks like this:

   ```
   MATCH (a:charlie), (b:economy), (c:bicycle)
   MERGE (a)-[:wants_make]->(b)-[:by_using]->(c);
   ```

   then it is saying both of these things:

   - Create a `wants_make` relationship between *every* `charlie` node and *every* `economy` node.
   - Create a `by_using` relationship between *every* `economy` node and *every* `bicycle` node.

   So, if the number of `charlie`, `economy`, and `bicycle` nodes are C, E, and B -- this results in (C * E * B) merges, which is a Cartesian product of a Cartesian product.

   Also, your data model seems to be wrong. For example, it seems much more reasonable to have a `Person` label instead of a `charlie` label.
2. A more reasonable query might look something like this:

   ```
   MERGE (a:Person {name: 'Charlie Brown'})
   MERGE (c:Bicycle {id: 123})
   MERGE (a)-[:wants_make]->(b:Economy)
   MERGE (b)-[:by_using]->(c);
   ```

   This query avoids Cartesian products by being more specific about the first and last nodes in the path, and it also avoids creating nodes and relationships that already exist.
3. And, going even further, you might want to combine `wants_make`, `Economy`, and `by_using` into a single `economizes_by_using` relationship:

   ```
   MERGE (a:Person {name: 'Charlie Brown'})
   MERGE (c:Bicycle {id: 123})
   MERGE (a)-[:economizes_by_using]->(c);
   ```

Comment: Nodes mentioned are unique, so maybe the clause was not so specific,; I'll try to match them through their IDs. Your point n°3 excludes node `a`and `c`from `b:economy` . Although it seems more logic it skip an important node in the graph scheme ( node `b`) . That's why I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to break up your query a bit:

```
MATCH (a:charlie), (b:economy), (c:bicycle)
MERGE (a)-[:wants_make]->(b), (b)->[:by_using]->(c)
```